# How to access TCA-fields in the Fluid template for a custom content element

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I've created a custom content element called `cat_but` (category button). I've added TCA and content element wizard without problem. The category button have only one field: sys_category. Exactly one category should be selected. From this, I want to render a link action to a controller using that category as argument. But how would I access the sys_category field from the Fluid template for the content element? There is no PHP class associated to the element, no? Or can I fetch `sys_category` from Typoscript? Or could I access the `tt_content` from a view helper?

**Edit**: Possibly feed `{data.uid}` to view-helper and from there look up categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your element `settings.sys_category`, then you should be able to access its value with `{settings.sys_category}` in the Fluid template, as well as from `$settings['sys_category']` in the Controller.

Otherwise, you will need to parse the `pi1_flexform` field of your content element. In Fluid, it could be done using a custom ViewHelper, or using some ViewHelpers provided by the [vhs](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html) extension.

Comment: Made a custom view-helper for this. Thanks for your answer!